# When is updated dataset visible on map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I built a simple map that uses a dataset for companies on a map. I update the dataset regularly but am really confused when changes are actually taking effect.

I used the [points on a map tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/help/add-points-pt-1/) as a start. I use the `queryRenderedFeatures` method to fetch all features from the dataset display them on a click.

I exported the dataset to a tileset which I then attached to a style. But whenever I make a change to the dataset, upload it to the tileset the changes are not visible immediately. Then I just click around in the interface doing little changes to the tileset, click publish and at some point I see the changes.

My questions here are:

- Is there a propagation period I have to wait for the changes to be visible?
- If yes: is there something I can do to trigger a change (preferably via API)?

Comment: Did you figure out this?  I am on the same boat. How did you fix this issue?